# Facebook Connect - get users friends score

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi can someone please tell me (Im using Facebook Connect Plugin for Phonegap) how I can get the users friends scores?

according to multiple sources all you should need to do is an API call to:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api( '/me/scores', ['user_friends'], function( response ) {

});
```

as the current permissions for this app are (from access token debug):

```
public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, email, publish_actions, user_friends, user_games_activity
```

but the response I get is always the same:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 39
  }
}
```

and if I use `/{appid}/scores` I get:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "147555555555", 
        "name": "Snowden Luke"
      }, 
      "score": 1005, 
      "application": {
        "name": "DFdfdf", 
        "namespace": "dfdfdfd", 
        "id": "5205555555583"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(its me!)

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/scores#readperms

```
/{app-id}/scores
```

returns

> Scores from this Facebook game for a user and their friends.

so, this seems to be the right endpoint for you. Concerning permissions, the docs say that

> A user access token is required to view scores by that user from **the app that generated the token**. If the user_friends permission has been granted, it will also returns friends' scores.

Questions:

- Are you sure your friends used the same app, and have posted scores?
- Are you using a correct Access Token (generated by the same app from whcih the scores came from)?

Comment: 1) yes, my partner has the same app installed. 2) I believe so. I will get hold of my partners phone tonight and debug the access token. will get back later thanks for the reply

Comment: managed to debug this. That permission wasn't set on her phone. But the documentation is incorrect. you have to first call /me/friends which gets all the friends that have that app installed and have accepted the "user_friends" permission. You then have to loop through them and call /{userID}/scores to get the application score. cheers!