# Facebook - highest scores

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently posted a question [Facebook Connect - get users friends score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638411/facebook-connect-get-users-friends-score) on how to get your friends high scores for your app. What I found was the following:

1) `/me/friends` with user_friends permissions to get friends with app installed and who have accepted this permission.
2) loop through `/{friendID}/scores` to get their high score.

I have not tested this fully as there are only 2 accounts with the app installed so I have the following question:

**im using `/me/friends?limit=10` as I only want the top ten high scores. Does this automatically bring back the highest or is there another parameter that needs setting to accomplish this?**

any information would be appreciated.

**edit**
Just found that `/me/friends?fields=score,picture` will return the all the data in one request. Just need to find out how to get the friends with the highest score

regards

Comment: The Graph API has no parameters for sorting the results, so I highly doubt that the results are in a certain order.

Answer (score 0):

If you call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/scores
```

It will actually return the scores for all your friends in descending order as you would like. When I do this for my application, I see:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "111", 
        "name": "..."
      }, 
      "score": 830, 
      "application": {
        …
      }
    }, 
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "222", 
        "name": "..."
      }, 
      "score": 330, 
      "application": {
        …
      }
    }, 
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "333", 
        "name": "..."
      }, 
      "score": 220, 
      "application": {
        …
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```